# Charan samaj and their history

Tags: history, sati-goddess

I am a chAraN (चारण in Devanagari), we usually call ourselves devi Putra (Son of Devi), we are the sons of Maa hinglaj.
I just want to know more about chAraN, I have seen we are mentioned in Ramayana, Mahabharata.

Does anyone have some content? About origin of chAraN it is written in the books that they used to live in Kailash prior to Mata Sati incident. After that, Lord Shiva sent us to the earth.

All the devi has taken birth in chAraN samaj. Like Karni Mata, Inder Baisa, Awad Mata, Ashapura Mata, Khodiyar Mata, Tanot Mata, Nagneecha Mata.

Any more information will be helpful.

Edit: As I already saw Wikipedia please do not copy paste that.

Comment: In Ramayana, chAraNa (चारण) were grouped alongwith Siddhas and were praised as mahAtma, (great souls).  They were described to be of having spiritual powers and perform journey in air. @yuvraj singh

Comment: Can you answer it, with little more facts.

Comment: You had stated that **they used to live in Kailash prior to Mata Sati incident**.  Can you explain? @yuvraj singh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ramayana, chAranAs were mentioned in Yuddha Kanda.  [In this site](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga108/yuddha_108_frame.htm) of Ramayana,  they were described as as Celestial bards.

> आविवेश महान् हर्षो देवानां **चारणैः** सह | रावने निहते रौद्रे
>   सर्वलोकभयंकरे || ६-१०८-३०
>
> When Ravana, the cruel demon and the terror of all the worlds, was
>   killed, a great rejoice filled the hearts of gods and ***chAranAs, the
>   celestial bards***.

---

While sending Vanara troop, under the leadership of Angada, Sugriva says chAranAs were residing on Mount Mahendra, from where Sri Hanuman jumped towards Lanka.

> नाना विधैः नगैः फुल्लैः लताभिः च उपशोभितम् || ४-४१-२१ देव ऋषि यक्ष
>   प्रवरैः अप्सरोभिः च सेवितम् | सिद्ध ***चारण*** संघैः च प्रकीर्णम् सुमनोहरम्
>   || ४-४१-२२ तम् उपैति सहस्राक्षः सदा पर्वसु पर्वसु |
>
> "***Mt. Mahendra*** is glorified with numerous kinds of flowered trees and
>   climbers. Important gods, sages, yaksha-s and even apsara-s will adore
>   it, and it is overspread with the groups of siddha-s and ***caarana-s***,
>   and thus it will be heart-stealing for a look. And the Thousand-eyed
>   Indra will always be visiting that Mt. Mahendra on every auspicious
>   day.

Sugriva even says that chAranAs are living on another Mountain by name Pushpitaka, was present after crossing 100 Yojanas from Lanka of Ravana.

म् अतिक्रम्य लक्ष्मीवान् समुद्रे शत योजने |
गिरिः पुष्पितको नाम सिद्ध ***चारण*** सेवितः || ४-४१-२८

"On crossing over that isle and after a hundred yojana-s a mountain named ***Pushpitaka*** is there in that august ocean, which is adored by the celestials like siddha-s, ***caarana-s***

---

They were also mentioned in Sundara Kanda, along with Siddhas.  They can move in air.

> शुश्रुवुश्चतदा शब्दमृषीणां भावितात्मनाम्| चारणानां च सिद्धानां
>   स्थितानांविमलेऽम्बरे|| ५-१-२८
>
> Then they heard words of ***Charanas***, Siddhas and pure hearted Rishis, who
>   were located in that clear sky.

---

After igniting the Lanka, Sri Hanuman doubts whether Sita was alive.  IT was then **chAranAs**, the **great souls** (**महात्मनाम्**) say that Sita was very much alive.

> स तथा चिन्तयन् तत्र देव्या धर्म परिग्रहम् | शुश्राव हनुमान् वाक्यम्
>   **चारणानाम् महात्मनाम्** || ५-५५-२९
>
> Hanuma, who was thus thinking there about the overpowering virtue of
>   Seetha, happened to hear the words of the **high-souled charanas**
>   (heavenly bards).

दग्धा इयम् नगरी लन्का साट्ट प्राकार तोरणा |
जानकी न च दग्धा इति विस्मयो अद्भुत एव नः || ५-५५-३२

"It is just so surprising a marvel to us that the entire City with its market-places, ramparts and arched door-ways, was burnt, but Seetha alone was not burnt."

---

***Edit: 6-11-2019***

After Sati, the wife of Shiva, turned into ashes, [Chaaranas, along with Devas](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226056.html), fought with the Ganas of Veerabhadra.  However, they were defeated by the Ganas of Veerabhara, and left the place of Yagna of Daksha.

Comment: Are you sure the Charanas the celestial beings and a community in Rajasthan are same? In Hinduism, there are many things which have same name but different meanings.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: I posted a comment under the question regarding Ramayana.  The OP asked to post the answer with details.  The OP stated that their ancestors used to live in Mount Kailash, before moving down to Earth.

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing, which I mentioned in my question.  @sarvabhouma,

Comment: @srimannarayna searcher Barber charan explaining Maa awad story you will get to know what we were.

Comment: I am satisfied with your answer, I am waiting for some more answer, surely you are one of the contenders of bounty.

Comment: THere are so many charan in Gujrat as well. One of the prominent author of Gujrati lit. Zaverchand Meghani wrote an unforgettable poem called Charan Kanya about bravery of Chran Girl.

Comment: @talk do you know more about charan

Comment: I will get back to you at the end of the day or tomorrow morning with an answer if possible or else I will comment on the missing info in this answer.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh: I have updated my answer. Please check.